# Every Java app crashes with divide by zero exception

Tags: windows-vista, java

I've tried two different apps, both of which crash on startup.

Here's an excerpt from the error log of the first app:

```
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO (0xc0000094) at pc=0x00000000697451a4, pid=5896, tid=5116
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0-b16 mixed mode windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [atiumd64.dll+0x2e51a4]
```

[Error log 1](http://ortz.pastebin.com/fd609f3c)

[Error log 2](http://ortz.pastebin.com/f6d430dfb)

I just updated Java and restarted a few minutes ago. Also, none of the apps on http://scratch.mit.edu/ load.

- 64-bit Vista
- AMD 64 X2 4800+ 2.5GHz

Comment: So no Java program works at all? Have you tried the 32-bit version of Java?

Comment: Right, no Java program works. I haven't tried the 32-bit version but everything worked a few days ago and I hadn't even restarted until I updated Java just a while ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm taking a guess here, but I did some Google searching and it looks like the `atiumd64.dll` file is part of the ATI Radeon driver package.  Have you recently updated this driver?  Or, if not, is there a newer version available that you could try?

Comment: I did upgrade recently. Unfortunately, it's the latest version.

Comment: Turns out it was the fault of the ATI Tray Tools profile I was using.